# Macbook will say it's charging, but it's not

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a Macbook Pro 13" i7 Early 2011 (MacbookPro8,1).  It's on its second battery (DP bq20z451 manufactured Dec 2012) from March 2015.  It was working fine for a while, but in the last month it's developed a problem and it's getting increasingly worse.

Sometimes even if the AC charger indicates it's charging (orange light), but the OS will say it is discharging. coconutBattery agrees.

Sometimes the battery will indicate it's charging, but when I remove the AC power it turns out it was not; the battery charge level will drop.  If this goes on long enough the laptop will power off because the battery has gone dead but the OS thought it was at 100%.  In this case, the lights on the battery agree it is out of power.

coconutBattery says the battery is in good condition, has 93% of its capacity, has only gone through 317 cycles, and is not overheating (30ºC).

My question is, ***is replacing the battery likely to fix this problem?*** Or is this indicative of a more serious problem?

Things I have tried:

- Shutdown.
- [Resetting the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).
- Different power adapters.

Comment: Sounds to me like what ever it is, the only thing left to do is to send it to be repaired, since you've already tried different power adapters.

Comment: I can replace the battery on my own.

Comment: Admittely a long shot, but sometimes the magsafe connector on the macbook side dirties up; often with small magnetic debris.  Try to clean it up with a cotton bud and a toothpick.  Worked for me once or twice.

Comment: Or try to find another charger which you can try out.  Perhaps it's partially fried.  It is a 5 years charger after all...

Comment: Safety tip: if there is a possibility that your new battery has failed, do not leave it charging unattended or overnight. There is a risk that one of the cells in the battery has failed and will overheat causing it to swell or rupture or damage the other cells by the excess heat and pressure.

Comment: If the DP bq20z451 was bought as a new official Apple battery in March 2015 then Apple will replace it. On my late 2011 MBP the inbuilt system report app (system information app) shows its official battery to be an SMC battery with device name bq20z451. This will also show the status of your battery ('normal' or 'replace now') and the state-of-charge and the max charge capacity and the charging status. In OSX 10.10 and 10.11 this app is in the /Applications/Utilities folder.

Comment: @MicChannel Unfortunately it was bought from a 3rd party. System Information shows the condition as `Normal`.

Comment: @Schwern OP: In that case, I would guess that your 3rd-party battery may be an unlucky early failure. I would replace it (again!) as the most likely (and cheapest) step you can take at this point. You may still have some consumer rights with the 3rd party battery supplier because it is only 11 months old. A failure at 317 cycles is poor, but many 3rd-party batteries are only rated to 500 cycles or so. Apple batteries should do a lot better (500-1000 cycles) though you will see some decrease in capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it today. It turns out the [Magsafe DC-in board](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Model-A1278-MagSafe-DC-In-Board/IF163-011-1) can be replaced. It's a little $25 part ($15 refurbished). I followed [the instructions on iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+MagSafe+DC-In+Board+Replacement/5152); you have to take apart practically the whole laptop which includes a lot of tiny, tiny connectors, but it's doable with just a few screwdrivers and a [spudger](https://www.ifixit.com/Tools/Spudger/IF145-002-2) I made from a chopstick.

[image: Macsafe DC-in board]

The battery now charges fine, and the laptop doesn't get nearly as hot (that could also be because I cleaned the heat sink).